# Invite guest to reoccurring weekly meeting in outlook once a month

Tags: microsoft-outlook, meetings

I have a weekly meeting with my sales team. I want to invite 1 of our VP's to the meeting but only on the first Monday of every month. Is it possible to do this without automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, is there any update?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule 2 invitations for the respective parties. 1 for the sales team with a weekly repeating frequency and for the VIP with a monthly repeating frequency.

Go to calendar and click on the date and create new event add your sales team members and set the repeat frequency to weekly and repeat the same process and add only the VIP member and set the repeat frequency to monthly.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could create a separate appointment recurrence with the same appointment time/title/location for your VP:

[image]